# Using the selected cell indexPath, UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios6, uicollectionview

Used `UICollectionView` to generate a seat map. So now which ever cell is selected, getting it's `indexPath` but how to use the selected cell `indexPath` in showing as row and seat no.
 Below is way i tried.

```
int ind = indexPath.item;
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ind]];
```

It gives output as below.

```
"<NSIndexPath 0x12135500> 2 indexes [0, 1]"
```

How to acces this thing and get only value 0,1.
Please guide for the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once look at this one,it'l helps you

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    int ind = indexPath.item;
    int section=indexPath.section;
    [arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",ind]];
    NSLog(@"%d,%d",section,ind);
}
```

Edit:

```
if([arr containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",ind]]){
        [arr removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",ind]];
    }
```

or

```
int n=[array indexOfObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",ind]];
    if([n<[array count]]){
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
```

Comment: but i want to ask how to delete the same from array.

Comment: find the object index from that array and delete the object using objectAtIndex: method.

Comment: @user2455507   [arrTotSelSeats removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",ind]]; this way not working.

Comment: hey are you there, i need some help can you please come to chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31399/discussion-between-iphone-programmatically-and-sathvik)